# Как из асинхронной функции получить синхронную функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

В плагине мне нужно получить данные из localstorage

```
function getAccessKeyId() {
    var a;

    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (result) {
        a = result.AWSAccessKeyId
    })

    console.log(a)
    return AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
}
```

в консоли выдает `undefined`

Comment: Может, логичнее использовать колбэк? или какой-нибудь другой подход, который выполняет действия после выполнения запросов. Например, promise.

Comment: А зачем? Чем вас асинхронщина не устроила?

Comment: Почитайте про `async/await`. Если сможете все грамотно реализовать -- получите псевдосинхронный код =)

Comment: По-хорошему – никак. JS так пронизан асинхронщиной не просто так. Асинхронность можно "прикрыть", спрятать, но не убрать.